# Ajax: Append data in input value instead of div

Tags: ajax, callback, append

This ajax function works fine, but now I would like to change the place where result needs to be shown

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
function submitForm1() {
var form1 = document.myform1;
var dataString1 = $(form1).serialize();
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'file.php',
cache: false,
data: dataString1,
success: function(data){
$('#results').html(data);
}
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="Place" id="Place" value="//append data here">
<div id="result"><div>
```

I need to have my result in value=" " after ajax call back.
Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$('#result').html(data);` instead `$('#results').html(data);` and you forget close your function

```
 function submitForm1() {
    var form1 = document.myform1;
    var dataString1 = $(form1).serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'file.php',
       cache: false,
       data: dataString1,
       success: function(data) {
         $('#result').html(data);
       }
     });
 }
```

Comment: this is what I already have(except mistyping). Data must go here: value=" "